# Why is my PHP, XSL, and XML not working?

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I have tried a multitude of things and I cannot get anything to load on the screen. The PHP loads the XML on the screen no problem, but when I add the XSL code in the PHP, the screen is then blank, no error or nothing. Can anyone see why?

Thank you

PHP file:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( 'books.xml' );

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load( 'books.xsl' );

$books = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "book" );

$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); // attach the xsl rules

foreach( $books as $book )
{
    $authors = $book->getElementsByTagName( "author" );
    $author = $authors->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $publishers = $book->getElementsByTagName( "publisher" );
    $publisher = $publishers->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $titles = $book->getElementsByTagName( "title" );
    $title = $titles->item(0)->nodeValue;

    echo $proc->transformToXML($doc);

    // echo "$title - $author - $publisher\n";
}    
?>
```

XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<books>
  <book>
    <author>Jack Herrington</author>
    <title>PHP Hacks</title>
    <publisher>O'Reilly</publisher>
  </book>
  <book>
    <author>Jack Herrington</author>
    <title>Podcasting Hacks</title>
    <publisher>O'Reilly</publisher>
  </book>
</books>
```

XSL file:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <body>
      <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>author</th>
            <th>title</th>
            <th>publisher</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="books/book">
            <tr>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="author"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="publisher"/></td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: where is $xml (used in your echo)?

Comment: Hey sorry I was testing with the echo and the last thing i tested was passing $xml to the transform method. Nothing works though :(

Comment: @deucalion0, Tebc was trying to draw your attention to the fact that your PHP code refers to a variable named $xml but defines no such variable.  The transformToXML method expects a DOM document as its argument; the DOM document you are trying to process is called $doc, not $xml, in your code.  It's not very surprising if transformToXML produces no output when passed no input.

Comment: I edited my code, I did have $doc in there originally but I was testing stuff and forgot to change it back :) Sorry

Comment: Any error in apache logs?

Comment: Have you tried 'View source' in the browser? You are outputting the HTML generated by the XSLT once for every book (twice using the XML in the question) - that seems an error to me

Comment: @MiMo is right.  You shouldn't be have the `echo` statement in the `foreach` loop. The `echo $proc->transformToXML($doc);` line should be moved outside of that loop (and the loop isn't really needed at all, except for debugging purposes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple , you need only this:

```
 $xsl = new DOMDocument;
 $xsl->load(  ($xsl_url));
 // Create new XSLTProcessor
 $xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
 // Load xsl stylesheet
 $xslt->importStylesheet($xsl);
 // Load XML input file
 $xml = new DOMDocument;
 $xml->load(  ($xml_url));
 // Transform to string
 $results = $xslt->transformToXML($xml);
 //response
 print $results;
```